# How to tell what specializations are compiled for a method?

Tags: julia

In the [performance tip](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/index.html#Be-aware-of-when-Julia-avoids-specializing-1), it says `f(x::Int...) = tuple(x...)` will not specialize. It also suggests to use `(@which f(...)).specializations` to check the specializations.

```
f(x::Int...) = tuple(x...)

f(1)
f(1, 2)
f(1, 2, 3)
f(1, 2, 3, 4)

a = first(methods(f)).specializations

Core.TypeMapEntry(Core.TypeMapEntry(nothing, Tuple{typeof(f),Int64}, nothing, svec(), 0x0000000000000001, 0xffffffffffffffff, MethodInstance for f(::Int64), true, true, false), Tuple{typeof(f),Int64,Vararg{Int64,N} where N}, nothing, svec(), 0x0000000000000001, 0xffffffffffffffff, MethodInstance for f(::Int64, ::Vararg{Int64,N} where N), false, true, true)
```

How do I interpret the `TypeMapEntry`?  How can I access it programatically (I find it hard to read from the output)? How many specializations has it made?

Answer (score 7):

The [MethodAnalysis](https://github.com/timholy/MethodAnalysis.jl) package, registered just this morning, should give you everything you need. (Your timing in asking this question was excellent!)

Comment: I smell a conspiracy! :D

Comment: It seems only too plausible, but it was a complete coincidence!